# Master Boot Record using GNU Assembly: extra bytes in flat binary output

Tags: gnu-assembler, mbr

I am try to compile the simple following MBR:

```
.code16
.globl _start
.text
_start: 
end:
    jmp end
; Don't bother with 0xAA55 yet
```

I run the following commands:

```
> as --32 -o boot.o boot.s
> ld -m elf_i386 boot.o --oformat=binary -o mbr  -Ttext 0x7c00
```

However, I get a binary file of more than 129MB which is strange to me. Thus,
I wanted to know what is going on in that build process ? Thank you very much.

Running objdump over boot.o give me:

```
> objdump -s boot.o
boot.o:     format de fichier elf32-i386

Contenu de la section .text :
 0000 ebfe                                 ..              
Contenu de la section .note.gnu.property :
 0000 04000000 18000000 05000000 474e5500  ............GNU.
 0010 020001c0 04000000 00000000 010001c0  ................
 0020 04000000 01000000
```

Manually removing the section *.note.gnu.property* before calling ld seems to solve the problem. However, I don't know why this section appears by default... Running the following build commands seems to solve the problem too:

```
> as --32 -o boot.o boot.s -mx86-used-note=no
> ld -m elf_i386 boot.o --oformat=binary -o mbr  -Ttext 0x7c00
```

Comment: What do you see if you `objdump` the file? That should shed some light.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu 20.04; my `mbr` file is 2 bytes.

Comment: I am on ArchLinux, Assembleur GNU (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1  The section is generated by the "as" command.

Answer (score 1):

using `-mx86-used-note=no` flag with as will remove note section.
Check here https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dOptions.html

> -mx86-used-note=no
>
> -mx86-used-note=yes
>
> These options control whether the assembler should generate GNU_PROPERTY_X86_ISA_1_USED and GNU_PROPERTY_X86_FEATURE_2_USED GNU
> property notes. The default can be controlled by the
> --enable-x86-used-note configure option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's an `as` option, not an `ld` option.

Comment: Also, this seems to be written as an answer to your question, [--oformat binary generates random gnu header instead of the given assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71289511).  It's not really answering this question, which already mentions the `-mx86-used-note=no` option, but is asking why it's needed and stuff like that.  That's why I wrote my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ld` links all your sections into the flat binary output unless you tell it not to (with a linker script for example).

The extra bytes are from the `.note.gnu.property` section which `as` adds, which can indicate stuff like x86 ISA version (e.g. AVX2+FMA+BMI2, Haswell feature level, is x86-64_v3.)  You don't want that in your flat binary, especially not at the default high address far from where you tell it to put your `.text` section with `-Ttext`; that would result in a huge file with zeros padding the gap since it's a flat binary.

Using `as -mx86-used-note=no` will omit that section from the `.o` in the first place, leaving only the sections you define in your asm source.  From [the GAS manual's i386 options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dOptions.html)

> `-mx86-used-note=no`
> `-mx86-used-note=yes`
>
> These options control whether the assembler should generate GNU_PROPERTY_X86_ISA_1_USED and GNU_PROPERTY_X86_FEATURE_2_USED GNU
> property notes. The default can be controlled by the
> --enable-x86-used-note configure option.