# --oformat binary generates random gnu header instead of the given assembly code

Tags: assembly, gcc, compilation, gnu, bare-metal

I am trying to write a bootloader code with Gnu as(trying it with nasm generates fine bin file). But i am getting this weird gnu headers in binary which wasn't intendend

```
0x00000000  0400 0000 2000 0000 0500 0000 474e 5500  .... .......GNU.
0x00000010  0200 01c0 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x00000020  0100 01c0 0400 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

assembly code look like this

```
.section text
.code16
.global init
init:
  jmp init
```

compiling it with `as boot.s -o boot.o`. if i check the hexdump of boot.o i see same headers

```
0x08000040  ffff ffff ffff ffff 0400 0000 2000 0000  ............ ...  
0x08000050  0500 0000 474e 5500 0200 01c0 0400 0000  ....GNU.........
0x08000060  0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 01c0 0400 0000  ................
0x08000070  0100 0000 0000 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
```

linking it with `ld -e init --oformat binary -o boot.bin boot.o`

Comment: Presumably it's linking the `.note.gnu.property` section, which you can see in the `.o` if you use `readelf -a`.  You didn't tell `as` or `ld` to omit that.  (e.g. with a linker script for `ld`)

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question.  Instead, post an actual *answer*, using the "answer my own question" button.  Or answer [Master Boot Record using GNU Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66909427) and mark this a duplicate.  Seems to be the only other mention of `-mx86-used-note=no` on SO.